Get a 3-Legged Token with Authorization Code Grant (PKCE) for Public Clients
tl;dr: Turns out it was an fetch-request error. Although, in the comments of the answer, it was found that you have to send the code_challenge as code_verifier to the /token-endpoint for making the PKCE-Auth work.
I am building a SPA for connecting to the AEC Data Model. I am following this authentication guide from APS, but i cannot get this to work. Specifically, my problem lies in "Step 3" where i get a "403 Forbidden" error.
There are many steps to make this work, but i am going to try and outline everything that i have done until now:
Create an App
I have successfully created a "Desktop, Mobile, Single-Page App" from the "Create Application" modal. I get a "Client ID" which i use for my app, and i have allowed for all API possible in the "API Access" box, among them the "AEC Data Model API". In this box, it says:

Premium APIs are unavailable for Authorization Code with PKCE grant type.

If i am correct, "AEC Data Model API" is not a premium API, as the "AEC Data Model API" does not aquire tokens, and therefore, this should not be an issue, but please correct me if i am wrong.

Custom Integration
After registering the app in "Applications", i add the "Client ID" to my organizations custom integrations.

OAuth authentication
I now follow this authentication guide.
Step 1: I create a code challenge and a code verifier:
{
    "code_challenge": "eJy4IjlN3Pu8ob27lc07Qw5RESB8lkyhWQlZcdllJf8",
    "code_verifier": "tjPmAq_gC-v91KZ4co9Yw_xiSCCpKX8LfWzKnHO5hRE"
}

And then i redirect the user to the following url:
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v2/authorize?client_id=WZJ7JVs9cnCJo70MpwNXbqoI4Y76eyG3RQqAkCUwx6rFjP5P&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5173&code_challenge=eJy4IjlN3Pu8ob27lc07Qw5RESB8lkyhWQlZcdllJf8&nonce=12321321&prompt=login&method=S256&response_type=code&scope=data%3Aread&state=just-any-state-right
Step 2: I sign in going through the auth flow and i successfully receive a code back (shown together with the verifier):
{
    "code": "ePJW9yuMwW2cR1co-Xmxq_Qwx629KfmGXYMIaJaO",
    "code_verifier": "tjPmAq_gC-v91KZ4co9Yw_xiSCCpKX8LfWzKnHO5hRE"
}

Step 3: I make a fetch request to get the access code. The endpoint is https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v2/token, and the content of the fetch is:
{
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    },
    "body": "{\"grant_type\":\"authorization_code\",\"client_id\":\"myapplicationclientidwhichihavehiddenhere\",\"code_verifier\":\"tjPmAq_gC-v91KZ4co9Yw_xiSCCpKX8LfWzKnHO5hRE\",\"code\":\"ePJW9yuMwW2cR1co-Xmxq_Qwx629KfmGXYMIaJaO\",\"redirect_uri\":\"http://localhost:5173\"}"
}

The response from the request is POST https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v2/token 403 (Forbidden).
I don't know what i can have done wrong, what can it be?


and the content of the fetch is:

The token endpoint does not want JSON, it wants "form encoding", i.e. application/x-www-form-urlencoded
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/reference/http/gettoken-POST/#resource-information:

Data Format: Form encoding (request); JSON (response)

Bold highlighting by me; The request is supposed to use form encoding, and the response you'll get, will be JSON.

Oh my, i am not used to doing "manual" fetch requests...
I am now getting an 400 (Bad Request) with an error_description instead, this might open up another issue or i'll be able to solve it now.

They got several possible reasons for a 400 response listed here, https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/reference/http/gettoken-POST/#http-status-code-summary - I'm guessing the error_description contains more info, which case it actually was?

Yeah, i am looking at the page right now, but i get this error:
{
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "The code_verifier sent does not match code_challenge included in the authorization request using the plain code_challenge_method."
}
I though i had the code challenge right, but i'll need to have a look at it again.

It works now! The error regarding the challenge was, that i was storing the code_verifier instead of the code_challenge. On the /token-endpoint, i have to send { code_verifier: code_challenge } instead of sending { code_verifier } in my body. According to the documentation you specified, this must surely be an error on APS side as the documentation says to store and send the code_verifier instead of the code_challenge to the /token-endpoint?

To satisfy application/x-www-form-urlencoded: I have to send ...&code_verifier=${code_challenge}&... instead of ...&code_verifier=${code_verifier}&... in the body request.
